# forEach and map with async function

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

I am trying to use a forEach and map inside an asynchronous function but this returns nothing.

Here is my code:

```
async function test(){

    const sqsMessages = [{"eventname":"\\core\\event\\user_list_viewed","component":"core","action":"viewed","target":"user_list","objecttable":"course","objectid":"2","crud":"r","edulevel":0,"contextid":25,"contextlevel":50,"contextinstanceid":"2","userid":"2","courseid":"2","relateduserid":null,"anonymous":0,"other":"{\"courseshortname\":\"324234\",\"coursefullname\":\"Teste\"}","timecreated":1572957245,"origin":"web","ip":"127.0.0.1","realuserid":null}];
    const queryValues = sqsMessages.forEach( logs => {
        return `(null,${ [
          ...Object.values(logs).map(async val => {
            if (typeof val === 'number') {
              return await val;
            }
            if (typeof val === 'string') {
              return await `'${val}'`;
            }
            return await `${val}`;
          }),
        ].join(',')})`;
      });


      return queryValues;
}
```

When i try to promise i got this error:

```
async function test(){

    const sqsMessages = [{"eventname":"\\core\\event\\user_list_viewed","component":"core","action":"viewed","target":"user_list","objecttable":"course","objectid":"2","crud":"r","edulevel":0,"contextid":25,"contextlevel":50,"contextinstanceid":"2","userid":"2","courseid":"2","relateduserid":null,"anonymous":0,"other":"{\"courseshortname\":\"324234\",\"coursefullname\":\"Teste\"}","timecreated":1572957245,"origin":"web","ip":"127.0.0.1","realuserid":null}];
    const queryValues = sqsMessages.forEach( logs => {
        return `(null,${ [
          ...Object.values(logs).map(async val => {
            if (typeof val === 'number') {
              return await val;
            }
            if (typeof val === 'string') {
              return await `'${val}'`;
            }
            return await `${val}`;
          }),
        ].join(',')})`;
      });

      const resultado = await Promise.all(queryValues);

      return resultado;
}
```

```
TypeError: undefined is not iterable
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: For default `forEach` not return any thing .You need to assign with some new array/object or else Try with map/reduce

Comment: What are you doing wrong? You are creating unreadable code.
What needs to be done? Split it into smaller functions so that each function does exactly one thing.